# Save output from loop to text file in R

Tags: r

Im trying to loop through a data frame to produce a text file with a specific format. Here is an example data frame:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- 10:1

df <- data.frame(x,y)
```

This loop will print text in the format I want it:

```
for (n in 1 : length(df[,1]))
{
  cat(paste("\n-insertblock weld\n", df[n,1], df[n,2], "\n1\n1\n0", sep = " "))
}
```

I would now like to do two things: 1) add the print to a txt file 2) add some more text to the top (will be the same for every file i produce). I have found this question which shows how to write txt to a file:
[Write lines of text to a file in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470248/write-lines-of-text-to-a-file-in-r)
And this one ([how to write to files with writeLines in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21566728/how-to-write-to-files-with-writelines-in-r)) tells me that `writeLines` needs things to be `as.character`. This is my attempt:

```
fileConn <- file("output.txt")
for (n in 1 : length(df[,1]))
{
  writeLines(cat(paste("\n-insertblock weld\n", as.character(df[n,1])), as.character(df[n,2]), "\n1\n1\n0", sep = " "), fileConn)
}
close(fileConn)
```

However, this gives an error:

> Error in writeLines(cat(paste("\n-insertblock weld\n",
>   as.character(df[n,  :    invalid 'text' argument

If I remove `cat` the error goes away but I only get the last line of the output:

```
for (n in 1 : length(df[,1]))
{
  writeLines(paste("\n-insertblock weld\n", as.character(df[n,1]), as.character(df[n,2]), "\n1\n1\n0", sep = " "), fileConn)
}
close(fileConn)

-insertblock weld
 10 1 
1
1
0
```

After I have created the correct txt file I need to add this to the top:

```
--simplenote
J
C
-36.413,33.568
5
0
```

Am i barking up the wrong tree with my method for saving the pasted text? Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sink("count.txt",split=FALSE,append = FALSE)

cat(paste("--simplenote\n","J\n","C\n","-36.413,33.568\n","5\n","0\n", sep = " "))

for (n in 1 : length(df[,1]))
{
  cat(paste("\n-insertblock weld\n", df[n,1], df[n,2], "\n1\n1\n0", sep = " "))
}
```